# Debugger can't find a source file in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse

I’m using Eclipse neon for C++ in Windows 10.

I’m trying to step into a program in debug and I keep getting this message Below.

**Can't find a source file at "/usr/src/debug/gcc-5.4.0-1/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/ostream.tcc" 
Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location.**

When I try locating the source file it is not there, probably because of the extension on the file search had “missing file” as an extension. But the file is actually their when I search it through windows.

I also tried specifying the mapping and I put c:\Eclipse Workspace where my projects are located and that didn’t work.

So I could really use your help,

Thank you,

Mike

Comment: What do you mean by this: "probably because of the extension on the file search had “missing file” as an extension"?

Comment: What I mean is the src file was missing because it was not searching the proper extention .cpp file.

Answer (score 1):

The answer:
Go to Preference >> Debug >> Source Lookup Path >> Add
Under compilation path: /cygdrive/c
Under Local file system path: C:\